# How to ONLY get property value

Tags: powershell

I want to retrieve IP Addresses from computer names but I ONLY want the IP nothing more.

```
$computer = 'Server1'
$computer = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computer) | select IPAddressToString
```

Returns @{IPAddressToString=x.x.x.x}. How do I return 'x.x.x.x'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your example, you'd type `$Computer.IPAddressToString` to return the array of IP addresses. If there is only 1 IP address for that hostname, then that's all there is. However, a hostname may have many addresses, and that's why it's an array. So if you only want to see the first IP address in the array, you could type `$Computer.IPAddressToString[0]`

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
| select IPAddressToString
```

With *(Powershell 2.0+)*

```
| select -First 1 -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
```

Or, in the case where you want to work with an array

```
| select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
```

This will give you an array of strings, so if you want individual addresses, use something like

```
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computer) | select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString)[0]
```

Comment: `-select -ExpandProperty Text` also worked for me when getting the inner text value (as opposed to the `@{Text=}` format) of a RadioButton whose declaration and whose Text values were all created programmatically from a function and an array, respectively. The missing piece was using `Select -ExpandProperty Text` instead of `Select-Object Text`.

Answer (score 1):

add ().IpAddressToString

```
([Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('Server1')).IpAddressToString
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way all the time with foreach, as opposed to select -expand:

```
$computer = 'Server1'
$computer = [Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computer) | foreach IPAddressToString
```